# Empty list returned when fetching conversations on Instagram Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

This is my current code to get the conversations for my IG profile:

```py
import requests

id = '<id>'
# URL and endpoint
url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{id}/conversations/"

# Parameters

params = {
    "platform": "instagram",
    "access_token": '<access_token>'
}

# Make the GET request
response = requests.get(url, params=params)

# Check the response status code (200 is OK)
print(f"Status Code: {response.status_code}")

# Print the response text to see the content
print(response.json())
```

To which I'm getting the output:

```json
Status Code: 200
{'data': []}
```

***Steps taken for this after research:***

- Enabled Connected Tools > Enable Access To Messages (on IG) [following this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/get-started)
- Created and connected a facebook page for the account
- Turned the account into a business account
- Published the app live
- Created another instagram account, under the same admin (with a page and turned to business) account on facebook and messaged both with each other
- Waited 30 days
- Allowed ALL permissions upon access token creation of account

Please help